# MySQL #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

A very interesting anomaly occurred today. A code that was perfectly working before started to misfire and as far as I know, it hasn't been changed for a long while.
It's an INSERT MySQL statement of the type (blabla) VALUES (blabla). Since the error was column count doesn't match, I rewrote it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ppl SET first_name = 'John', last_name = 'Smith', middle_name = '',
nick_name = '', address = '', gender = 'M', city = '', zip_code = '', birthday = '',
email = 'test@test.com', phone = '', alt_phone = '', comments = ''
```

Still the same error! Ok, I thought I'm bad at counting, so I logged on to PHPMyAdmin, browsed to the table, selected the INSERT from there, filled in all the fields and I still got the exact same error message. Assuming that PHPMyAdmin does know how to count, any suggestions?

EDIT:
Per the comments below: the problem was actually caused by a trigger that was modified!

Comment: Strange indeed. Can you provide the CREATE TABLE statement so we can try it out as well?

Comment: Come to think of it - there's no triggers on that table that may cause the issue?

Comment: Come to think of it - that's something that I did not check! Turns out there was a change in one of the triggers indeed which was causing all the troubles. Thank you so much!